# How does the safe bool idiom bool_type (and the safe bool idiom) work?

Tags: c++, safe-bool-idiom

I was pointed to the 'safe bool idiom', and after trying to decipher what is going on (the explanation [supplied on the site](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool2.html) was not sufficient enough to grant me understanding of *why* it works), I decided to try to take the following code apart and make an attempt at simplifying it as much as possible. The site supplied code below:

```
class Testable {
    bool ok_;
    typedef void (Testable::*bool_type)() const;
    void this_type_does_not_support_comparisons() const {}
  public:
    explicit Testable(bool b=true):ok_(b) {}

    operator bool_type() const {
      return ok_==true ? 
        &Testable::this_type_does_not_support_comparisons : 0;
    }
  };
```

I decided to analyse the key basis of 'bool_type' given this seems to be what it's centred on. Given the following line:

```
typedef void (Testable::*bool_type)() const;
```

One can (not so easily, due to bracketing) deduce it's a typedef of a type of 'void Testable::*', of which bool_type represents. This can be further demonstrated by making the following modifications and function calls:

```
class Testable {
    bool ok_;
    typedef void (Testable::*bool_type)() const;
    void this_type_does_not_support_comparisons() const {}
  public:
    explicit Testable(bool b=true):ok_(b) {}

    bool_type Test; //Added this

    operator bool_type() const {
      return ok_==true ?
        &Testable::this_type_does_not_support_comparisons : 0;
    }
  };

int main()
{
    Testable Test;
    int A = Test.Test; //Compiler will give a conversion error, telling us what type .Test is in the process
}
```

It allows us to see what type bool_type is:

> error: cannot convert 'void (Testable::*)()const' to 'int' in initialization

Which shows it is indeed a type of 'void (Testable::*)'.

The issues crops up here:

If we modify the following function:

```
    operator bool_type() const {
      return ok_==true ? 
        &Testable::this_type_does_not_support_comparisons : 0;
    }
```

And turn it into:

```
    operator void Testable::* () const //Same as bool_type, right? 
    {
      return ok_==true ? 
        &Testable::this_type_does_not_support_comparisons : 0;
    }
```

It generates the following complaints:

> error: expected identifier before '*' token
>   error: '< invalid operator >' declared as function returning a function

My questions are thus:

Why is it generating those complaints if 'void (Testable::*) is indeed the typedef for bool_type?

And

What is going on here?

Comment: Why does a person put one question in the title, and then a quite different one in the text? Not to mention *two* such very different questions?

Comment: What's the question? `bool_type` is a pointer-to-member-function, pointing to a function of type `void Testable::some_function() const`. There's no confusion "due to bracketing" (although the C++ declaration syntax is not exactly the epitome of beauty).

Comment: I never said the word confusion, I just said it wasn't easy to deduce (Testable::*bool_type) would, on first glance, appear to be a pointer to a variable called bool_type. Except it's not, given the typedef implies the last word used is typedef after everything preceeding it. Even though it's bracketed (which runs contrary to precedence).

Comment: @Alf Point is, why is the replacement for bool_type not working? And also, I don't see how it's different from the title (What is going on here? = How does the safe bool idiom work?; Why is it generating those complaints = how does the bool_type work). I just think you're being pedantic.

Comment: @SSight3: the title question is about an anti-pattern (using evil implicit conversions while using rube goldberg like technique to avoid one particular pitfall), while the questions in the text are concerned with C++ syntax only.

Comment: @Alf: I wrote the title. Nothing to do with 'anti-patterns' or whatever - just how exactly does it work (in the sense of an incredulous question). Only on stack overflow can I get two seasoned programmers debate syntax of a question rather than answer the question, whilst another one actually answers the question without needing comments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning goes wrong about here

```
operator void Testable::* () const //Same as bool_type, right?
```

This isn't correct. The type of bool_type is, as the compiler tells us in the error message:

> 'void (Testable::*)()const'

So, to replace it in the operator, you would need something like

```
operator (void (Testable::*)() const) () const
```

if that is ever possible! See why even the ugly typedef is an improvement?

In C++11 we also have the new construct `explicit operator bool()` to save us from this ugliness.

Comment: Let me guess, explicit makes it only work for bools? Clever idea. And thank you for actually answering the question.

Comment: `s/answering the question/making a really good guess at what the question was/`